# Eloquent hasMany filter and eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm creating an application with Laravel and I'm trying to work with Eloquent. I have two tables : Orders and Items.

Each items has a type (int data) :

- 1 => book
- 2 => video

Each order has ONE book and many videos.

In my Order model, I would like to have a book and others items relationships. So, I have this code :

```
public function book()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item')->where('type', 1)->first();
}

public function others()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item')->where('type', '!=', 1)->get();
}
```

But, if I use eager loading with my relationship, I got an error :

```
Order::with(['book', 'others'])->get();
```

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define relationships like this to make your code work:

```
public function book()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Item')->where('type', 1);
}

public function others()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item')->where('type', '!=', 1);
}
```

But it's better to define relationships without `where` constraints:

```
public function book()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Item');
}

public function others()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}
```

And then do this:

```
Order::with(['book' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('type', 1);
    },
    'others' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('type', '!=', 1);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hi Alexey,

It works for others thanks ! But for book relationship, I get an array with one object instead of directly an object...

Comment: @D.Durand I've just tested it and you're getting an object. Make sure you're using `hasOne` relationship. To get a book you still need to load a collection of orders with books and others and iterate over it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I use hasMany instead of hasOne !  

Last question : why do you say is better to not use where inside relationships ?

Comment: @D.Durand because you'll want to reuse these relationships. If you're using `where` to filter data, at least use custom names like `bookTypeScifi`.